# I am constantly facing transient failure on "add-migration" command

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am working on .Net 7 project and I have installed the following libraries for the Code First Approach:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.tools.

Problem:
I am constantly facing the following error;

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database 'StudentManagementDB' on server 'DESKTOP-MEAB4ET'.
```

"An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer' call".

Initially it was working fine but I deleted migrations and mydb from SSMS several times and faced this error.

Following is my Connection string; "Server=DESKTOP-MEAB4ET;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"

Note: Same DB string is working in another project.

Comment: What is the details error stacktrace? Could you please share that? Are the versions are correct and other nuget packages are alright can you share those version details? Need to check your dbcontext class, program.cs file and the nuget package details. Please share those details.

Comment: My Program.cs Class:

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer
                (
                    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")
                );
                options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
            });

All the versions are correct.

Comment: Exception is saying the error is in "StudentManagementDB" where as the connection string posted is pointing to "mydb" database. check that

Comment: Could you include the full stacktrace within the question and your other configuration so that the issue can be reproduced?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved. Migration has a conflict with SeedData() method and the exception thrown by the application is so vague. After continuous debugging of 2 days I finally got the solution.

Thanks for the replies.